# Using brew to Install GNU flex on OS X but got an error "/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig is not writable."

Tags: macos, homebrew, flex-lexer

I need compile some LEX/YACC files(`*.l`) under OS X. And `GNU flex` is needed as a scanner.

However, I was stuck while installing GNU flex.

1. Run `brew install flex`, but got an error:

   - `` Error: You must `brew link xz' before flex can be installed ``

   Then I run `brew link xz`, still got an error:

   - `Error: Could not symlink lib/pkgconfig/liblzma.pc
     /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig is not writable.`

How to install flex on OS X 10.10 correctly? Is this problem caused by my `home brew`?

---

Some details about my 'brew':

Run `brew doctor`

```
Warning: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig isn't writable.

This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a formula tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably `chown` /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

Run `ls` command

`yeze@yezedeMacBook-Pro:~$ ls -la /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   136 Mar 31  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x  30 yeze  admin  1020 Oct  1 21:05 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   405 Mar 30  2013 tcl.pc
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   404 Mar 30  2013 tk.pc`

Comment: What is the output of `brew doctor` and `ls -la /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`?

Comment: @xhruso00 Actually, I don't quite understand the rule... seems you have answered some questions like "Unable to install Xcode 5 under Yosemite". I think mine is of the same type, so where should I ask this kind of question?

Comment: Add them to the question.

Comment: I don't think your question is kind of "software tools commonly used by programmers". That's the difference

Comment: @xhruso00 Thanks, I will pay more attention to question quality.

Answer (score 3):

This question is caused by `brew`.

When you got `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig is not writable.`, you should run:

`chown [YourAccountName] /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`

Then follow the instruction, run `brew link xz`. You may get a response like that :`Linking /usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.1... 53 symlinks created`

Finally, try `brew install flex` again, it will work.

*Best thanks @IKavanagh.*

Comment: or, chown $USER /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig